# Command Line Macros in Comments using SLURM

Tags: bash, shell-script, slurm

In my opinion, comments are comments are comments. They should NEVER change program state. Sadly, the people over at [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/) disagree.

SLURM requires the following syntax (or something similar) to exist at the front of a .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=5:00:00    
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024M

MyProgram.exe
```

The above will submit a request to run the program `MyProgram.exe` using 8 processors on my school's super computer. I'm currently benchmarking my code and would like to use a command line argument to change the number of processors. Effectually, I want to do the following

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=5:00:00    
#SBATCH --ntasks=%1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024M

MyProgram.exe
```

where `%1` would be a command line argument. I would then call it as `sbatch myShScript.sh 123` which would use 123 processors. This, of course, does not work because bash interprets the `#SBATCH --ntasks=%1` line as a comment (which it is) and never subs in my command line argument.

Is there a way to trick SLURM or BASH into subbing in my command line argument?

Comment: Why aren't you just giving these switches via the command line? That' what they're for. `sbatch --ntasks=10 my.sh`. This can be wrapped into an alias instead, or a shell script or `Makefile` that you call instead.

Comment: @slm, thanks. I'm a little newish to the art of BASH and didn't realize that I could pass the SLURM commands at the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the processing done by SLURM (by [`sbatch`](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/sbatch.html), specifically) is done before bash is invoked, so bash won't help you here. The script could be in any language, it wouldn't matter: the `#SBATCH` are only coincidentally bash comments, what matters is that they're `sbatch` directives.

Options can be specified in the file so as to provide a convenient way to always use the same parameters for a particular script. If you want to use different options, pass them on the command line of `sbatch`. You can write a wrapper script that runs `sbatch` if you want to build up options from certain specific parameters. You can pass the job script as standard input (a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is convenient) instead of keeping it in a separate file if you prefer.

```
#!/bin/sh
sbatch --time=5:00:00 --ntasks="$1" --mem-per-cpu=1024M <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
MyProgram.exe
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks very promising but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. Regarding your code snippet, is that spread across two files? How would I call the wrapper?

Comment: I figured something out. I ran `sbatch --time=5:00:00 --ntasks=4 --mem-per-cpu=1024M ShScriptThatCallsMyProgram.sh`. Thanks for the help! (Is what I've done what you were intending?)

Comment: @chessofnerd - no that's a single script that is using a [HEREDOC](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (<<EOF) that "tricks" the command `sbatch` into thinking it received a file, when it in fact is receiving the contents via cli.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I will look into that. The `<<EOF` syntax tricked VIM as well (: